# SELECT STATEMENT of certain columns don't return anything in CnosDB

Tags: time-series, cnosdb

Following the CnosDB [QuickStart](https://docs.cnosdb.com/guide/quick_start.html), I am now able to create database, table and insert some data. But SELECT STATEMENT of certain columns don't return anything.

Here are the steps to double check:

```
CREATE DATABASE oceanic_station;

CREATE TABLE air (
    visibility DOUBLE,
    temperature DOUBLE,
    presssure DOUBLE,
    TAGS(station)
);

INSERT INTO air (TIME, station, visibility, temperature, presssure) VALUES 
                (1666165200290401000, 'XiaoMaiDao', 56, 69, 77);

SELECT * FROM air; // SELECT * works as expected

select time, station, visibility, temperature, presssure from air; // SELECT all columns   works as expected

select time, station, visibility from air; / SELECT time column, tag column and some non-tag columns works as expected
```

The following 3 queries don't return anything:

```
select time from air;
select station from air;
select time, station from air;
```

See the screenshot here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The select operation requires a field， we may optimize this behavior in later release version